# Rails PostgreSQL check if column is virtual

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, virtual-column

PostgreSQL 12 has a cool [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) feature but I can't check whether column is virtual or not in Rails.

For reference, MySQL Adapter in Rails [allows](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubydocrus/rails/ActiveRecord%2FConnectionAdapters%2FAbstractMysqlAdapter:supports_virtual_columns%3F) you to do like

```
MyModel.supports_virtual_columns?
=> true
MyModel.columns.last.virtual?
=> false
```

But in PostgreSQL Adapter you can't do the same despite it does support Generated fields?

Rails v.5.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that PostgreSQL 12 implements generated columns doesn't mean that you're going to have the interface through the Rails PostgreSQLAdapter to check whether a column is virtual or not because it's not implemented (yet).

If you see in the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter` the code for `supports_virtual_columns?` is pretty simple:

```
def supports_virtual_columns?
  mariadb? || database_version >= "5.7.5"
end
```

While the code to check if a column is virtual or not is stated as:

```
def virtual?
  /\b(?:VIRTUAL|STORED|PERSISTENT)\b/.match?(extra)
end
```

Which checks if the Extra value returned from a

```
SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM table_name;
```

query for that column matches with VIRTUAL, STORED or PERSISTENT, if so, it returns true.

But this doesn't exist in the PostgreSQL counterpart. `supports_virtual_columns?` will return false in any adapter where this feature isn't developed, as it's defined in the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter` to return false:

```
# Does this adapter support virtual columns?
def supports_virtual_columns?
  false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This function is available for Postgres [as of Rails 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/column.rb#L21) so you can now use `MyModel.columns.last.virtual?` just like you do with MySQL.